# copying rows in a table into the same table with a different id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I'm trying to copy rows in a table but I need it with a different id, that can be in that table aswell. Both id and second_id are primary key. and foreign keys.

```
+----+-----------+
| id | second_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  1 |         2 |
|  1 |         3 |
|  2 |         2 |
+----+-----------+
```

So I need to copy all of second_id of id 1 to the id 2, but and eventually, if there's going to be id 3, copy that aswell.

the result should be

```
+----+-----------+
| id | second_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  1 |         2 |
|  1 |         3 |
|  2 |         2 |
|  2 |         1 |
|  2 |         3 |
+----+-----------+
```

Also id is a foreign key, so if I have id 3 copy it aswell just like id 2
Any solutions ?

Comment: show us your sample data and desire result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: write expected result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self-join of the table to get all the combinations of `id` and `second_id`. Then use a `LEFT JOIN` to filter out the combinations that already exist, so you can insert the rest into the table.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (id, second_id)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t2.second_id
FROM yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable AS t2
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t3 ON t1.id = t3.id AND t2.second_id = t3.second_id
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e0b6/1)

Instead of the `LEFT JOIN` you could simply use `INSERT IGNORE`. Since `(id, second_id)` is the primary key, the duplicates will simply be ignored when inserting.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO yourTable (id, second_id)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t2.second_id
FROM yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN yourTable AS t2
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ffae/1)